# Is it possible to reference a variable via string manipulation?

Tags: sql

I have a series of datetime variables that need to be referenced, and the key to which variable needs referencing is reached by using substring on another field.  I can create the name of the variable as a string using string manipulation, something like this:

```
'@' + SUBSTRING(field, CHARINDEX(',', field) + 2, LEN(field) - CHARINDEX(',', field) + 1) + 'start'
```

Is there a way to get SQL to recognize that this is the name of one of my variables?  Some kind of function to convert the string?

Comment: Can you post the input and output you expect ?

Comment: You can only do this by passing the variable name into dynamic SQL, and to do that you need to pass the variable reference into an `EXECUTE sp_executesql` call. See the links in the comments above.